# how can I invoke a callback function in jquery without using trigger?

Tags: jquery

```
$('input:required').keyup(function () { 
    if(isEmpty($(this))){
        $(this).next().text("Required Field");
    }
    else{
        $(this).next().text("");
        validateField($(this));
    }
});
```

wanted to invoke keyUp without triggering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `.keyup()`, `.trigger('keyup')` or `.triggerHandler('heyup')` to let jQuery handle this correctly.

Another way might be to extract the function, give it a name and invoke it with `.call(inputElement)` or `.apply(inputElement)` (you have to bind it, because you use the `this`-keyword).

Example:

```
function inputCallback() { 
    if(isEmpty($(this))){
        $(this).next().text("Required Field");
    } else {
        $(this).next().text("");
        validateField($(this));
    }
}
let input = $('input:required').keyup(inputCallback);

// with apply or call:
if(input.length) inputCallback.apply(input.get(0));

// with jQuery trigger-function:
input.keyup();
```